# Is this set consider a set that all of its elements are subsets as well?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So basically I have been searching and thinking on this task for the past $2$ hour and I am still not sure if I got it all right.I have to create an infinite set that all of its elements are also proper subsets of that set. So I was thinking if I have a set that contains the natural numbers $A=\{1,2,3\cdots \}$ and I define a $X–n$ ($X–n$ is contained in the natural numbers and $n$ is contained in the natural numbers) so $X_n=\{1,2,3....\}$ and $A/ X_n!$ = an empty set. Would that mean that I have came to the conclusion that $X_n\subset A$.

Comment: If all of its elements are proper subsets, they are in particular sets, so that elements must be sets.

Comment: I must say though, that basically you're being asked to create an infinite ordinal-like construct. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals).

Comment: I have seen it and I am able to understand it or at least I think so.The main problem is that I am not sure how to write it down in a formal way.

Comment: Is the natural number 7 a set?  If not $7 \not \in A$ because $A$ only has sets as elements.  But some classes would say $7 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (and $6 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ etc. and $0 = \emptyset$ in which case you may be okay.  But I think they are trying to get you to think entirely in terms of sets and nothing else.

Comment: Yeah that is the point.I think I got it.Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: So hint:  Let $A_0 = \emptyset$.  Let $A_i = \cup_{0\le k < i} A_k$.  Let $B = \cup_{n\in \mathbb N+\{0\}}A_n$.  Any element is  $A_i = \cup_{0\le k < i}A_k\subset B$

Comment: Of course.... I'm not sure how one was supposed to come up with that on one's own.  I imagine nearly all of us were taught that so it becomes something we either know or we don't.  Hat's off to anyone who *did* come up with it on their own.  I know I wasn't one of them.